pytorch-lightningで，スカラーのテンソルにtensor.item()としているにもかかわらず同様にせよとのエラーが出る
pytorch-lightningを使用していて，以下のエラーが出ています．：
IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() in Python or tensor.item<T>() in C++ to convert a 0-dim tensor to a number Output is truncated.
そこで，登場するテンソルのうち形状がスカラーのものはすべて.item()としたのですが，同様のエラーが出ます．
このモデルは8クラス分類を行う問題で，ラベルは0か1です．
具体的には，8つの感情について，感情が存在すれば1，そうでなければ0といった具合です．
何かお気づきの点がある方はもちろん，こうしてみたらどうか，などの提案でも構いませんのでどうぞご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします．
データセットとモデルは以下の通りです：
##### Dataset #####
class WrimeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_length):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.data = dataframe
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.data.iloc[idx]['input_text']
        row = self.data.iloc[idx]
        labels = row['label'] 

        # 入力テキストの前処理
        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            "感情分析：" + text,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )

        input_ids = inputs['input_ids'].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.long)
        attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask'].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.long)

        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        # shape: torch.Size([8])
        
        padding_sign = torch.full((self.max_length,), -100, dtype=torch.long)
        actual_length = min(len(inputs), self.max_length)
        padding_sign[:actual_length] = input_ids[:actual_length]
        print(f'input_ids shape: {input_ids.shape}')
        print(f'attention_mask shape: {attention_mask.shape}')
        print(f'labels shape: {labels.shape}')
        return input_ids, attention_mask, labels


##### model #####
class T5Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(T5Model, self).__init__()
        model_name = "sonoisa/t5-base-japanese"
        config = T5Config.from_pretrained(model_name, output_hidden_states=True)
        self.t5_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.acc = Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes)
        self.f1 = F1Score(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes)
        self.qwk = CohenKappa(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes, weights='quadratic')
        self.class_acc = Accuracy(task='binary')
        self.class_f1 = F1Score(task='binary')
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.d_model, num_classes)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        for param in self.t5_model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

        for param in self.classifier.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True
        

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        output = self.t5_model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = output.loss
        print(f'loss shape: {loss.shape}')
        decoder_hidden_states = output.decoder_hidden_states
        last_decoder_state = decoder_hidden_states[-1][:, -1, :]
        print(f'last_hidden_state: {last_decoder_state.shape}')
        logits = self.classifier(last_decoder_state)
        print(f'logits shape: {logits.shape}')
        preds = self.sigmoid(logits)
        print(f'preds shape: {preds.shape}')
        return loss, preds, logits
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, attention_mask, labels = batch
        print('==training==')
        print(f'input_ids shape: {input_ids.shape}')
        print(f'attention_mask shape: {attention_mask.shape}')
        print(f'labels shape: {labels.shape}')
        loss, preds, logits = self.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss.item())
        return loss.item()
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, attention_mask, labels = batch
        print('==validation==')
        print(f'input_ids shape: {input_ids.shape}')
        print(f'attention_mask shape: {attention_mask.shape}')
        print(f'labels shape: {labels.shape}')
        loss, preds, logits = self.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        
        labels = labels.bool()
        self.acc.update(preds, labels)
        self.f1.update(preds, labels)
        self.qwk.update(preds, labels)
        
        self.log('val_loss', loss.item())

        return {'loss': loss.item(), 'preds': preds, 'labels': labels}
        
    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        # エポックの終わりにメトリクスの平均を計算し、ログに記録
        self.log('val_acc', self.acc.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('val_f1', self.f1.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('val_qwk', self.qwk.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

        for i in range(self.num_classes):
            self.log(f'val_class_{i}_acc', self.class_acc[i].compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
            self.log(f'val_class_{i}_f1', self.class_f1[i].compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
            self.class_acc[i].reset()
            self.class_f1[i].reset()
            
        # メトリクスをリセット
        self.acc.reset()
        self.f1.reset()
        self.qwk.reset()

        

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = Adafactor(
            self.parameters(),
            scale_parameter=True,
            relative_step=True,
            warmup_init=True,
            lr=None)  # Adafactorはlrを自動的に調整する
        return optimizer

また，エラーの全文は以下の通りです：
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[84], line 31
     28 trainer = make_trainer(max_epochs=max_epochs, name='test', patience=patience)
     30 try:
---> 31     trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
     32 except KeyError as e:
     33     print(f"KeyError: {e}")

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:544, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    542 self.state.status = TrainerStatus.RUNNING
    543 self.training = True
--> 544 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    545     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    546 )

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\call.py:44, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     42     if trainer.strategy.launcher is not None:
     43         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
---> 44     return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     46 except _TunerExitException:
     47     _call_teardown_hook(trainer)

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:580, in Trainer._fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    573 assert self.state.fn is not None
...
   1075 def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> "CompositionalMetric":
   1076     """Construct compositional metric using the get item operator."""
-> 1077     return CompositionalMetric(lambda x: x[idx], self, None)

IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use `tensor.item()` in Python or `tensor.item<T>()` in C++ to convert a 0-dim tensor to a number
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

エラー文の中でCompositionalMetric(lambda x: x[idx], self, Noneとあるので評価指数の計算時に問題が生じているのではないかと考えています．
printでテンソルの形状を出力させたところ，以下のような形状でした：
input_ids shape: torch.Size([10])
attention_mask shape: torch.Size([10])
labels shape: torch.Size([8])
input_ids shape: torch.Size([10])
attention_mask shape: torch.Size([10])
labels shape: torch.Size([8])
==validation==
input_ids shape: torch.Size([2, 10])
attention_mask shape: torch.Size([2, 10])
labels shape: torch.Size([2, 8])
loss shape: torch.Size([])
last_hidden_state: torch.Size([2, 768])
logits shape: torch.Size([2, 8])
preds shape: torch.Size([2, 8])

2はbatch_sizeを表しており，10はmax_lengthです．
何か少しでもお気づきの点がある方がいらっしゃいましたら，ご教示いただけますと幸いです．
また，環境は以下の通りです：
Windows11
VSCode==1.88.1
PyTorch==2.1.2
pytorch-lightning==2.0.8

よろしくお願いいたします．
2024/05/08追記
torchmetricsでの評価指数の計算をあきらめsklearnを用いたところ解決しました．
しかし，根本的な解決策ではないため引き続きお気づきの点がある方はご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします．

以下の点について確認するのはどうでしょうか。

テンソルの形状の扱い:

input_ids や attention_mask は、予想通りの形状 (バッチサイズ、シーケンス長) を持っているようですが、labels の形状が異なっています。labels が期待する形状は、通常各バッチに対応するラベルの配列です。エラーメッセージが指し示すように、0次元のテンソルへの不正なインデックス参照が問題を引き起こしています。ラベルの形状を確認し、必要に応じてバッチ処理を調整することが求められます。


データセットの __getitem__ メソッド:

データセットの __getitem__ メソッドで、labels をテンソルに変換していますが、この形状がバッチ処理に適切かどうか確認が必要です。labels の形状が各バッチで一貫していない場合、それがエラーの原因になる可能性があります。


モデルの forward メソッド:

labels を再度テンソルに変換していますが、これは不要かもしれません。labels はすでにデータセットからテンソルとして受け取っているはずです。また、loss の形状を出力していますが、loss は通常スカラー値です。エラーの内容から、何かしらのインデックスアクセスが loss に不適切に適用されている可能性があります。



解決策の提案

ラベルの形状の確認と調整:

labels の形状が各バッチで一貫しているか確認し、適切な形状に調整してください。PyTorchでは、通常クラス分類のためのラベルは形状 (バッチサイズ, ) であるべきです。


不要なテンソル変換の削除:

forward メソッド内で labels を再度テンソルに変換する処理を削除してください。


メトリクス計算の確認:

validation_step 内でのメトリクス計算時にエラーが発生している可能性があります。特に、preds と labels の形状が互換性があるか確認してください。また、0次元テンソルに対する不適切な操作がないかも再確認してください。




コメントをありがとうございます！
質問文が情報不足でした．
このモデルは8クラス分類を行う問題で，ラベルは0か1です．
したがって，labelsの形状は(batch_size, 8)となる気がするのですがいかがでしょうか？predsの形状もlabelsと同様になっています．
